# Botón no llama a la función

Tags: javascript, html, bucle-for, function, onclick

Tengo que crear un programa que le pida al usuario la cantidad de palabras que desea escribir por medio de un ; usando 2 botones, el primero debe de llamar a los windows.prompt necesarios para que el usuario ingrese sus palabras y el segundo debe imprimir estas palabras en un Text Area. Sin embargo, cuando hago click en el primer botón, este no llama a la función. Adjunto códigos para su análisis, además de tener dudas en si el ciclo for está bien implementado

Código HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
    <script src="otro.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <h1>Este programa solicita escribir al usuario cuantas palabras desée, y estas serán mostradas en un Área de texto</h1>
        <h2>Ingrese cuantas palabras desea ingresar</h2>
        Escriba la cantidad de palabras:<input type="number" id="cantp" placeholder="Escríba aquí" min="1" required>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="escribir palabras" onclick="ingresar()">
        <br><br><br>
        <input type="button" value="Escribir la lista de palabras" onclick="imprimir()">
        <input type="reset" value="Borrar"><br><br>
        Resultado:<br><textarea id="lp" rows="20" cols="20"></textarea>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Código js:

```
function ingresar(){
    lp="";  
    for (i=1;i<=document.getElementById('cantp').value;i++){ 
        palabra= window.prompt("Introduce la palabra no. "+i); 
        lp=lp+palabra+"\n"; 
    } 
function imprimir(){
    document.getElementById("lp").value=lp;
```

Comment: Podría verificar que en el for el valor de document.getElementById... sea un número. Por otro lado la función imprimir está definida dentro de la función ingresar intenta separarla para que funcione

Answer (score 0):

El único error en tu código es que a la función `ingresar()` le faltaba el corchete de cierre (`}`). Lo mismo para la función `imprimir()`. El programa parece funcionar correctamente arreglando esos dos detalles.

```js
function ingresar() {
  lp = "";
  for (i = 1; i <= document.getElementById('cantp').value; i++) {
    palabra = window.prompt("Introduce la palabra no. " + i);
    lp = lp + palabra + "\n";
  }
}

function imprimir() {
  document.getElementById("lp").value = lp;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <h1>Este programa solicita escribir al usuario cuantas palabras desée, y estas serán mostradas en un Área de texto</h1>
    <h2>Ingrese cuantas palabras desea ingresar</h2>
    Escriba la cantidad de palabras:<input type="number" id="cantp" placeholder="Escríba aquí" min="1" required>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="escribir palabras" onclick="ingresar()">
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Escribir la lista de palabras" onclick="imprimir()">
    <input type="reset" value="Borrar"><br><br>
    Resultado:<br><textarea id="lp" rows="20" cols="20"></textarea>
</form>
```